# Converting date using to_datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am still quite new to Python, so please excuse my basic question.

After a reset of pandas grouped dataframe, I get the following:

```
    year    month   pl
0   2010    1   27.4376
1   2010    2   29.2314
2   2010    3   33.5714
3   2010    4   37.2986
4   2010    5   36.6971
5   2010    6   35.9329
```

I would like to merge year and month to one column in pandas datetime format.

I am trying:

```
C3['date']=pandas.to_datetime(C3.year + C3.month, format='%Y-%m')
```

But it gives me a date like this:

```
    year    month   pl  date
0   2010    1   27.4376 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002011
```

What is the correct way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert to `str` if necessary, then `zfill` the month col and pass this with a valid format to `to_datetime`:

```
In [303]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str) + df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2), format='%Y%m')
df

Out[303]:
   year  month       pl       date
0  2010      1  27.4376 2010-01-01
1  2010      2  29.2314 2010-02-01
2  2010      3  33.5714 2010-03-01
3  2010      4  37.2986 2010-04-01
4  2010      5  36.6971 2010-05-01
5  2010      6  35.9329 2010-06-01
```

If the conversion is unnecessary then the following should work:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'] + df['month'].str.zfill(2), format='%Y%m')
```

Your attempt failed as it treated the value as epoch time:

```
In [305]:
pd.to_datetime(20101, format='%Y-%m')

Out[305]:
Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000020101')
```